# eliminar elementos duplicados arreglo javascript con vue js

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

Tengo los siguientes datos en json que se almacen en mi data vue js

```
proveedoresSeleccionados: [{id: 1, texto: "ORSIS S.A.C", check: false },
                          {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
                          {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
                          {id: 3, texto: "ERT S.A.C" , check: false},
                          {id: 4, texto: "APPLE S.A.C" , check: false}]
```

estoy intentando con esto pero no me devuelve nada.

```
 const resultado = uniq(this.proveedoresSeleccionados.filter((proveedor)=> {
           proveedor.id
        }).map((proveedor)=>{
          return proveedor;
        }))
```

Alguna sugerencia como puedo hacer para obtener una nueva matriz pero de elementos no repetidos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes la solución clásica de recorrer el array de objetos en un bucle pero creo que es más elegante utilizar [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/reduce) filtrando por el valor que quieras (`id` o `texto`)

```html
<script>

var proveedoresSeleccionados = [{id: 1, texto: "ORSIS S.A.C", check: false },
                          {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
                          {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
                          {id: 3, texto: "ERT S.A.C" , check: false},
                          {id: 4, texto: "APPLE S.A.C" , check: false}]

console.log(
Object.values(proveedoresSeleccionados.reduce((prev,next)=>Object.assign(prev,{[next.texto]:next}),{})));


</script>
```

**Edito con una explicación al código**:

Lo primero, `Reduce` ejecuta la función indicada **por cada elemento** del `array`. En este caso la función a ejecutar sería:

```
function(prev,next){
return Object.assign(prev,{[next.text]:next}),{});
}
```

Que con expresiones de tipo flecha queda resumida a:

```
(prev,next)=>Object.assign(prev,{[next.texto]:next}),{}));
```

`Reduce` puede tomar 4 valores:

> - valorAnterior
> - valorActual
> - indiceActual
> - array
>
> La primera vez que se llama la función, `valorAnterior` y `valorActual`
>   pueden tener uno de dos valores. Si se proveyó un `valorInicial` al
>   llamar a `reduce`, entonces `valorAnterior` será igual al `valorInicial` y
>   `valorActual` será igual al primer elemento del `array`. Si no se proveyó
>   un `valorInicial`, entonces `valorAnterior` será igual al primer valor en
>   el `array` y `valorActual` será el segundo.

En este caso utilizaremos dos (el valor de la iteración anterior y el valor de la actual (`prev` y `next`))

Y llamaremos a `Object.assign()`. Como indica la documentación:

> El método **Object.assign()** se utiliza para copiar los valores de todas
>   la propiedades enumerables de uno o más objetos fuente a un objeto
>   destino. Retorna el objeto destino

Además:

> **Las propiedades en el objeto destino serán sobrescritas por las
>   propiedades en las fuentes si tienen la misma clave**. Propiedades
>   posteriores de las fuentes podrán sobrescribir las anteriores.

Es decir, vamos a copiar en un nuevo `array` de objetos los elementos que estamos iterando a través de `reduce` aprovechándonos de la característica que tiene `assign` de sobrescribir objetos si están repetidos.

Así pues, en la primera iteración toma el objeto:

```
 {id: 1, texto: "ORSIS S.A.C", check: false }
```

Y lo mete en el nuevo `array` de objetos siempre y cuando no exista ya un objeto con el mismo valor de la propiedad `texto` ({[next.texto]:next}). **Es importante devolver el valor como un objeto (entre llaves) para que en la siguiente iteración pueda acceder a la propiedad `texto` del objeto.**.

En la segunda iteración hará lo mismo con el objeto:

```
{id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false }
```

Y como no existe ningún objeto todavía con el texto "ABS S.A.C" lo meterá sin problemas.

En la siguiente iteración obtendrá el objeto:

```
{id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false }
```

Y como ya existe un `texto` igual sobrescribirá el que ya existe en el `array`.

Con esto conseguimos un nuevo array con identificadores únicos (he filtrado por `texto` pero podrías hacerlo por `id`)

Espero haberme explicado :)

Comment: como funciona tu  funcion? podrias explicarme? a que te refieres con esta linea   Object.assign(prev,{[next.texto]:next}),{})))

Comment: Si me quedo claro tu explicacion Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

puedes probar utilizando cualquiera de las dos soluciones:

El objeto **Set** te permite almacenar valores únicos de cualquier tipo

```js
var proveedoresSeleccionados = [
  {id: 1, texto: "ORSIS S.A.C", check: false },
  {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
  {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
  {id: 3, texto: "ERT S.A.C" , check: false},
  {id: 4, texto: "APPLE S.A.C" , check: false}
]
var unique = [...new Set(proveedoresSeleccionados.map(item => item.texto))]             

console.log(unique)
```

Utilizando Array.filter para determinar que valores eliminar después de mapearlo

```js
var proveedoresSeleccionados = [
  {id: 1, texto: "ORSIS S.A.C", check: false },
  {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
  {id: 2, texto: "ABS S.A.C",check: false },
  {id: 3, texto: "ERT S.A.C" , check: false},
  {id: 4, texto: "APPLE S.A.C" , check: false}
]
var unique = proveedoresSeleccionados.map(item => item.texto)
  .filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
  
console.log(unique)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo cree una funcion tambien para filtrar por si alguien quiere usarla tambien.

```
function remove_duplicates(arreglo) {
    var no_duplicate = arreglo.filter((objeto, index, self) =>
     index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.id === objeto.id 
    )));
    return no_duplicate 
  }
```